# Where can I find the IEEE list of research topics?

Tags: ieee

I'm trying to submit to IEEE Transactions on Computers, and their web form offers an 8-line box with a list of hundreds of topics to choose from.  The web form does not identify the list, but I am sure it is published elsewhere.

Can someone link the topics list that IEEE is using?

edit: I used a regex replace to mine the list from the page source, but the link might still be helpful to others.  It has 2261 items, to be exact, and you can view 8 of them at a time.

This link has the up-to-date list as of August 2016 (and I will not be keeping it up to date): http://alejandroerickson.com/j/eggs/IEEE-Keyword-Ontology-2016-08-18.html

**From IEEE:**
https://www.computer.org/cms/Computer.org/peer-review/docs/taxonomy.pdf

Below are two items from the list, for identification purposes:

C.2.1.h Network topology < C.2.1 Network Architecture and Design < C.2 Communication/Networking and Information Technology < C C

G.1.7.d Differential-algebraic equations < G.1.7 Ordinary Differential Equations < G.1 Numerical Analysis < G Mathematics of Computing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IEEE makes their 'Taxonomy' available [on line](https://www.ieee.org/documents/taxonomy_v101.pdf) (linked to in their Author FAQ under the Publications page), but this is only a hierarchical list without the designations you have given to identify something as the C.2.1.h topic. Surprisingly (to me), neither the author kit nor the editorial manual discuss this hierarchy.

In contrast, for the American Institute of Physics, the PACS codes are available on-line at [PACS 2010](https://publishing.aip.org/publishing/pacs/pacs-2010-regular-edition).

Comment: wow, they didn't put in the section numbers (as you point out)!  Thanks